# Understanding the math behind velocity-dependent conservative forces, Part 1

Tags: mathematical-physics

In a notable answer to [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/31672/what-causes-a-force-field-to-be-nonconservative), Qmechanic formulates conditions for "conservative"  velocity-dependent forces (e.g. the Lorentz force, but not velocity-proportional friction) that are analogous to those for traditional velocity-independent conservative forces.

To wit, in a simply-connected domain (for the velocity-independent case, anyway), two sets of three equivalent conditions for a force to be conservative are presented:

$$ \begin{array} {cccc}
\text{ } & \text{velocity-independent force } \boldsymbol{F}( \boldsymbol{r}(t)) & | 
 & \text{velocity-dependent force } \boldsymbol{F}(\boldsymbol{r}(t),\boldsymbol{\dot{r}}(t)) \\
1) & F_i = - \frac{\partial U}{\partial x^i} & | & 
 F_i = -\frac{\partial U}{\partial x^i} + \frac{d}{dt} \left( \frac{\partial U}{\partial \dot{x}_i} \right) \\
2) & \boldsymbol{\nabla \times F} = 0 & | & 
 \frac{\delta F_i(t)}{\delta x_j(t')} - \frac{\delta F_j(t')}{\delta x_i(t)} = 0 \\
3) & \oint_{S^1} dt \, \boldsymbol{F}(\boldsymbol{r}(t)) \boldsymbol{\cdot \, \dot{r}} (t) = 0 & | & 
 \oint_{S^2} dt \wedge ds \, \boldsymbol{F} ( \boldsymbol{r}(t,s), 
  \boldsymbol{\dot{r}}(t,s)) \boldsymbol{\cdot \, r'}(t,s) = 0
\end {array}
$$
where  $\delta$ denotes a [functional derivative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional-derivative), the final integral is over any "two-cycle $r: S^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3 \,$", and "a dot and a prime mean differentiation wrt. $t$ and $s$, respectively".
I have changed the formulation somewhat; I hope I didn't introduce errors.

I get the maths for the velocity-independent force conditions, but, for the velocity-dependent case, I am a bit puzzled by the functional derivatives and totally baffled by the two-cycle integral.

My question:

- What is this "two-cycle integral", which looks like no surface integral I've ever seen, and how is it evaluated? (and how did $\boldsymbol{r}$ acquire two arguments?).

  > - How is this functional derivative evaluated?
  >  - Why are the functional derivative and two-sided integral equivalent to each other and to the potential formula for the force?

  I suspect this is a rather large subject; references would be appreciated.

Comment: What exactly do you want to know about the functional derivatives and/or two-cycle integral? You have all the makings of a very good question here except that you don't actually ask the question. ;-)

Comment: Well, yes, you end with a question mark so it's technically a question, but asking "where can I read about X?" in a specific context like this one is just a copout for asking X directly. For example, you could ask "What does a functional derivative mean?" and it would be a _much_ better question. Or "What is a two-cycle integral?" Or some such thing.

Comment: Right, but questions on this site are supposed to be specific. Ask one thing, get one thing answered. Then if you want to know more, you post a followup question, or use what you were given in the original answer to find more information. Here's another way to look at it: answers will _always_ provide references when there is interesting further reading. So by asking for references explicitly, you're eliminating a large class of potential answers, namely those which directly explain the thing you want to know without referring you to an external resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We assume that OP is mainly concerned with condition (3').

A) Recall first that for forces ${\bf F}={\bf F}({\bf r})$ that do not dependent on velocity, we may use condition (3) to extend a definition of potential energy $U({\bf r}_{0})$ at a fiducial point ${\bf r}_{0}$ to a potential energy

$$\tag{A} U({\bf r}_{1})~:=~U({\bf r}_{0})-\int_{[0,1]} \!\mathrm{d}s~ {\bf F}({\bf r}(s)) \cdot {\bf  r}^{\prime}(s) $$

at any other point ${\bf r}_{1}$ along any curve ${\bf r}: [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}^3$ with boundary conditions

$${\bf r}(s\!=\!0)={\bf r}_{0}\qquad\text{and}\qquad{\bf r}(s\!=\!1)={\bf r}_{1}.$$

Condition (3) ensures that definition (A) does not depend on the curve. Infinitesimally, definition (A) leads to

$$ \delta U~=~-{\bf F}\cdot \delta{\bf  r}, $$

which implies condition (1).

A') We now repeat this for velocity dependent forces ${\bf F}={\bf F}({\bf r},{\bf v})$. The only difference is that points are replaced by paths that satisfy pertinent boundary conditions (BC). We may use condition (3') to extend a definition of potential action $S_{\rm pot}[{\bf r}_{0}]$ at a fiducial path ${\bf r}_{0}:[t_i,t_f]\to \mathbb{R}^3$ to a potential action

$$\tag{A'} S_{\rm pot}[{\bf r}_{1}]~:=~S_{\rm pot}[{\bf r}_{0}]-\int_{[t_i,t_f]\times [0,1]} \!\mathrm{d}t \wedge \mathrm{d}s~ {\bf F}({\bf r}(t,s),\dot{\bf r}(t,s)) \cdot {\bf  r}^{\prime}(t,s) . $$

at any other path ${\bf r}_{1}:[t_i,t_f]\to \mathbb{R}^3$ along any [homotopy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy) ${\bf r}:[t_i,t_f]\times [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}^3$ with boundary conditions

$${\bf r}(t,s\!=\!0)={\bf r}_{0}(t)\qquad\text{and}\qquad{\bf r}(t,s\!=\!1)={\bf r}_{1}(t).$$

Condition (3') ensures that definition (A') does not depend on the homotopy. Infinitesimally, definition (A') leads to

$$ \delta S_{\rm pot}~=~-\int_{[t_i,t_f]} \!\mathrm{d}t~{\bf F} \cdot \delta{\bf r}, $$

which implies condition (1') under suitable BC.

Comment: Thx v much.  I don't grok it yet, but you've laid out the generalization clearly.  I suspect a typo just after (A'):  should it be "at any other path r_1 : ..." ?

Comment: @ArtBrown: Thanks, I corrected the typo in an update.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that this is mostly a case of fancy notation being confusing.

Independent of the physical interpretation, the surface integral simply is an integral over a sphere in 3-space (which has to be paramatrized by two variables, called s and t here).

Furthermore, the definition of the functional derivative (as customarily used in physics) can be found in a reference from the answer you mentioned yourself, as well as on [its wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_derivative#Using_the_delta_function_as_a_test_function).
As far as the connection between the two goes, I wouldn't know. I hope this can get you started though

Comment: Thank you for the link.  My apologies, I've decided to split the question up into 3 parts, so now a portion of your answer looks like a non sequitor...

Comment: Are you referring to the part about the integral?

Comment: Actually, the part about the functional derivative.  I'm going to save that part for a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

It took me an embarrassingly long time to understand Qmechanic's construction, so I  thought I would add this elaboration, as an aid to anyone as perplexed as I was.

I think this integral (3') is best understood not as a surface integral but as a line integral, just not of your garden-variety gradient of a scalar function ($-\boldsymbol{\nabla} U$ , like 3). Instead, it's the line integral of a [functional derivative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_derivative), thus accounting for the second integration.  To wit:

One starts with a functional $S_{pot}(\boldsymbol{r})$, depending on a path function $\boldsymbol{r}(t)$ and its time derivative $\boldsymbol{\dot{r}}(t)$, with boundary conditions established at an initial time $t_i$ and final time $t_f$:
$$ S_{pot}(\boldsymbol{r}) = \int_{t_i}^{t_f} L[\boldsymbol{r}(t),\boldsymbol{\dot{r}}(t)] dt $$

Question: given the value of this functional $S_{pot}(\boldsymbol{r_0})$ for a "reference" path $\boldsymbol{r_0}(t)$, how does one calculate its value $S_{pot}(\boldsymbol{r_1})$ for a new path $\boldsymbol{r_1}(t)$?

Well, the functional derivative tells us how this functional changes in response to a small change in the path $\boldsymbol{r}(t) \rightarrow \boldsymbol{r}(t) + \boldsymbol{ \delta r}(t) $:

$$ \delta S_{pot} = \int_{t_i}^{t_f} \frac{\delta S_{pot}}{\boldsymbol{\delta r}} \cdot \boldsymbol{\delta r} $$

where 
$$ \frac{\delta S_{pot}}{\boldsymbol{\delta r}} = \frac{\partial L}{\partial \boldsymbol{r}} - \frac{d}{dt} \frac{\partial L}{\partial \boldsymbol{\dot{r}}} = - \boldsymbol{F}(\boldsymbol{r},\boldsymbol{\dot{r}})$$

So, one can now construct a sequence of intermediate paths (a continuous contour of paths in the limit) that smoothly deforms the reference path to the new path, introducing a new parameter $s$ to denote position along the contour.  Using the same identifier $\boldsymbol{r}$ for the entire contour as for its elements (here's where $\boldsymbol{r}$ acquires a second argument), the contour is denoted:

$$ \boldsymbol{r}(t,s) , \text{ where } \boldsymbol{r}(t,0)=\boldsymbol{r_0}(t) \text{ and }  \boldsymbol{r}(t,1)=\boldsymbol{r_1}(t)$$

Along this contour (as opposed to along the path from $t_i$ to $t_f$), $\boldsymbol{\delta r}(t,s)= \boldsymbol{r}'(t,s) \, ds$ , where the "$'$" denotes differentiation with respect to $s$ (to distinguish it from differentiation wrt $t$).  It follows that:

$$ S(\boldsymbol{r_1}) = S(\boldsymbol{r_0}) + \int_0^1 ds  \int_{t_i}^{t_f} dt \frac{\delta S_{pot}}{\boldsymbol{\delta r}} \cdot  \boldsymbol{r}'(t,s) = S(\boldsymbol{r_0}) - \int_0^1 ds  \int_{t_i}^{t_f} dt \, \boldsymbol{F}(\boldsymbol{r}(t,s), \boldsymbol{\dot{r}}(t,s)) \cdot  \boldsymbol{r}'(t,s)$$

For this result to be contour-independent, a round-trip around any closed $s$-contour must integrate to $0$:

$$ \oint ds  \int_{t_i}^{t_f} dt \, \boldsymbol{F}(\boldsymbol{r}(t,s), \boldsymbol{\dot{r}}(t,s)) \cdot  \boldsymbol{r}'(t,s) = 0 $$

Voila.

Again, there's nothing here that isn't already in Qmechanic's answer.

Apparently Volterra originated these ideas.  You can find his work [online](http://ebooks.library.cornell.edu/m/math/) in Cornell's Historical Math Monographs, particularly Chapter II of his 1913 *Leçons sur les fonctions de lignes*.  The presentation is straightforward, clear, and ... in French.