# Electric field lines forming closed loops

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-induction, conservative-field

I have been reading about the electric field induced on a metal ring due to an increasing magnetic field directed along the axis of the ring and the electric field lines are found to form concentric circular loops. This implies that the electric field formed is not conservative. Why is it so? Are electric field due to free charges and those due to changing magnetic field two entirety different  things? 
Please provide an intuitive and less mathematical explanation as I am just a high school student with knowledge of basic calculus.

Comment: Related https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/31672/what-causes-a-force-field-to-be-non-conservative?noredirect=1&lq=1 https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/303922/is-electric-field-not-a-conservative-field-when-its-produced-by-change-of-magne

Comment: That the field forms closed concentric circular loops implies that it is divergence-free, not that it is non-conservative. For example the B-field around a current-carrying wire forms closed circular loops and *is* conservative.

Comment: @RobJeffries I meant that the field thus formed is 'not' conservative'.

Comment: Also related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/75349/if-electromagnetic-induction-generates-a-potential-difference-in-a-loop-where-a

Answer (score 2):

If a vector field $\mathbf E$ is the gradient of a conservative potential $\phi$ then its curl must be zero i.e.

$$ \nabla \times \mathbf E = 0 $$

because [the curl of the gradient of any continuously twice-differentiable scalar field is always the zero vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_calculus_identities#Curl_of_the_gradient). However Maxwell's equations tell us:

$$ \nabla \times \mathbf E = -\frac{\partial \mathbf B}{\partial t} $$

and in the presence of time dependent magnetic fields the right hand side is not zero so there is no conservative scalar potential from which the electric field is derived.

Looking at it another way, we can write the electric field as a function of the usual scalar potential and [the magnetic vector potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_potential#Magnetic_vector_potential):

$${\bf E} = -\nabla \phi -\frac{\partial {\bf A}}{\partial t}$$

So once again we see that if the presence of time dependent magnetic fields the electric field isn't simply due to a conservative potential.

Comment: Unlikely to be helpful given the last sentence of the question.

Comment: @RobJeffries: Gautham and I discussed this [in the chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/39427183#39427183), which I think was productive. This answer is more of a *for the record* post. If you want to venture a more intuitive approach please do.

Comment: swell hat and glasses, john. merry xmas to you.