# Magnetic induced electric field and vice versa

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-fields

Well it is known that electric fields originated due to changing magnetic field has different properties from those than formed due to static charges. My doubts:

1. Why is it so? Is it something we had to assume. Or some logical reason behind it. Ex:
   Closed line integral of electric field isn't zero in former etc.
2. Is magnetic field induced due to changing electric field (after maxwell) also different.

Comment: It is not well known that different electric fields have 'different properties' - Maxwell pretty well captured them all in a few equations.

Comment: Is that really so? Don't we know everything about this? Why so?

Comment: Maxwell's equations capture all known electric and magnetic fields. Period.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Electric field lines forming closed loops](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/352009/)

Answer (score 0):

A system with changing magnetic fields would emit quantized electromagnetic radiation (photons) at frequencies determined by the time course of the changes in magnetic field intensity. Static charges do  alter the electric field but would not be emitting photons. A changing electric field would similarly emit photons. The second question is not clear as to what feature of magnetism you want compared to what other feature.