# Forces acting on a point and change of reference frame

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, inertial-frames, conservative-field

Given a point mass, with $\underline{x}$ the position vector, on which acts a force $\underline{F}$ such that it is conservative:

$$\underline{F}= -\nabla U(\underline{x}) .$$

Then if I change frame of reference from a inertial one to a non-inertial one, it 
is true that the (total) force (meaning the vector sum of all the forces acting w.r.t. the new frame of reference) remains conservative?

Answer (score 1):

Well, it depends on your definition of a [conservative force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservative_force). If you allow potentials to depend on velocity (which many authors do not!), in the spirit of my Phys.SE answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/82375/2451), then *Yes:* you can define a velocity-dependent potential for the fictitious forces (in particular for the velocity-dependent Coriolis force), see e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/498165/2451) Phys.SE post. The total force will then be sum of your above force and fictitious forces.

Comment: Yes, indeed when passing from one reference to another there are corrective terms which, in general, yeld a velocity dependent potential. The fact is that I know that are verified the Lagrange equations for $L=T-U$ for purely positional potentials, so I don't know if this is still the case when $U=U(x,\dot{x})$.