# Are the gradient field are the only fields which are only conservative?

Tags: forces, classical-mechanics, potential-energy, vector-fields, conservative-field

I have found that gradient fields are always conservative. But for my knowledge I wanna ask "are the gradient fields are only fields which are conservative"?  I mean is it necessary that a field which is conservative has to be a gradient field of some scalar function?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/31672/2451 and links therein.

Comment: The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservative_force#Mathematical_description) on conservative forces directly answers your question.