# Definition of non-conservative force

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, work, potential-energy, definition, conservative-field

In defining [conservative force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservative_force), we say that

> "The potential energy difference is path independent."

However, as far as I understand, potential energy only exists when there is a force field.

People say one example of non-conservative force.

By definition, non-conservative force should be the one in which the difference in potential energy is path dependent. But where is potential energy for friction which is not a force field?

Comment: Can you give  a reference? Potential energy is something we can define for conservative forces, but you are right, if they are not conservative then there is no potential energy associated with them

Comment: Hint: The correct definition refers to work, not potential energy.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What causes a force field to be "non-conservative?"](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/31672/)

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean to say a conservative force $\mathbf F$ is one where we can define a potential energy $U$ such that
$$\mathbf F=-\nabla U$$

Then the work done by that force is independent of the path and only depends on the endpoints of the path. In other words, the work is given by:
$$W=\int\mathbf F\cdot\text d\mathbf l=\int(-\nabla U)\cdot\text d\mathbf l=U_{\text{start}}-U_{\text{end}}$$
by the fundamental theorem of calculus.

On the other hand, we cannot express a non-conservative force in terms of a potential energy. Therefore, we cannot apply the fundamental theorem of calculus to the work integral, and therefore there is a path dependence on the work.

Comment: Thank you very much for edit my question (con - "with"). Thank you again.