# If $\oint_C [q\vec{V} \times \vec{B}] \cdot d\vec{l}=0$, then why $\vec{F}=q\vec{V} \times \vec{B}$ isn't conservative?

Tags: electromagnetism

If $\oint_C [q\vec{V} \times \vec{B}] \cdot d\vec{l}=0$, then why $\vec{F}=q\vec{V} \times \vec{B}$ isn't conservative ?

Comment: it is velocity-dependent. The usual statement that the vanishing of the line-integral for all closed curves implies the existence of a potential holds for position-dependent vector fields only. See [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/82375/203278) for more.