# Is there any physical scalar potential where $U$ is also depends on $\dot q_i$s?

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, potential, potential-energy, velocity

In the book of *Classical Mechanics* by Goldstein, at page 21, while deriving the Lagrange's equation, when the external forces are derivable from a scalar potential $U$, the author implicitly assumes that $U = U(q_i, t)$.

However, is there any physical scalar potential where $U$ is also depends on $\dot q_i$s ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, e.g. the velocity-dependent potentials for the Lorentz force and the Coriolis force. See also e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/15894/2451) Phys.SE post.

Comment: my technical knowledge on EMT is very limited, so I couldn't think that.Thanks for the answer.